# In-App purchase for a short-term license

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to allow a user to buy the right to some functionality in my app for a day or a couple of days. As far as I know, subscriptions are for a minimum of one month so they aren't useful for this.

So I was thinking of using a simple consumable. But then I have the question of what happens if a user uninstalls and reinstalls the app. I don't want him to lose the purchase. And consumables aren't persisted in the app's purchase history. So how do I preserve it?

The only way I've found is to keep track on my server. But that's a problem too, because any identifier I may store on the device will be erased as soon as the app is uninstalled, so how will my server recognize the device/account?

Also, if possible, I would like to have an IAP persist across devices of one person, though that's not that important. Just mentioning it in case you have a solution for that as well.

So, is there any way to solve this? Some common practice for doing this, perhaps? Please don't discard a solution because it's too obvious. I've never done this before so I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: "a day or a couple of days" how many reinstalls will there be?.. wouldn't even bother.